# Remove white strip at the bottom of view in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xcode4.2

This is a view with a background color of Black. As you can see, there is a small white strip at the bottom of the view. I need to remove this white strip.

[image: HERE]

I am working in Xcode 4.2. I found a few possible solutions on your site as:

```
-viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,20.0,320.0,460.0);
```

and

```
[[viewController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
```

But I do not recognize where I have to write these codes. I have set the background color as black. I have tried to set the property of view. but it is disabled. So please help me out.

Comment: viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0);Use this one because your navigation bar is hidden ,so that's why you need to set frame to cover entire screen.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I am helpless.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the size of the view

```
[[viewController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)];
```

and try may this helps you....

try this code in viewWillAppear method..

Comment: I have these codes into my codes as:-                [[splashscreencontroller view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)]; But i found an error "Class +view not found.